# How can I display data obtained with a service in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I have a service that downloads some data from the web but when I try to pass it to an activity to have it shown to the user I receive the following error:

E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

```
// This gets populated in the server based on information from a server.
byte[] downloadedData; 
// Instantiated downloadedData from server connection, code removed for brevity. 

// Try to start activity with downloaded data.
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("DATA", downloadedData);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Why is your service trying to start an activity? You do not know what the user is doing in the foreground. Use an event bus (e.g., greenrobot's EventBus) to offer this data to your UI, if it happens to be in the foreground. If the event is ignored, the service can save the data to a file and raise a `Notification` to let the user know that the data is ready. In general, "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" is because your `Intent` is much too big.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @CommonsWare, but what if I can't use event bus for my app?

Comment: "what if I can't use event bus for my app?" -- why can't you? Event buses work for thousands upon thousands of developers.

Comment: Thank you once again @CommonsWare for your reply. I can't use event bus because my UI and service run on separate processes.

Comment: Then put them in the same process. Or, have the activity bind to the service while it is in the foreground, providing a callback object that you can use for sending results back. If the activity is unbound, raise a `Notification`. Note that even with the binding, you may need to shrink the results, or save them to disk where the activity can load them into its own process.

Answer (score 0):

Try

**1.** Register custom broadcast receiver in your activity

```
context.registerReceiver (myBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter ("CUSTOM_ACTION"));
private final BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver () {

    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Do something
    }
};
```

**2.** Send broadcast from your service

```
Intent intent = new Intent ("CUSTOM_ACTION");
intent.putExtra("DATA", downloadedData);
context.sendBroadcast (intent)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I have the same problem I get "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION".